# Evento onclick em uma lista mostrar uma imagem

Tags: html5

Preciso de ajuda em um evento `onclick`:

Ao clicar em um texto dentro de uma lista `<ul><li>`. Gostaria que mostrasse uma imagem em uma `div` ao lado.

Como faço isso?

Comment: deixa a `div` com a atributo css `display: none` e quando clicar no elemento muda pra `display: block` por exemplo

Comment: Ricardo... teria algum exemplo pra indicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicando em um elemento da lista a imagem vai aparecer na `div` e o texto vai mudar, e ao clicar de novo volta como era. Explicação do código comentado no `script` com `//comentário aqui`

```js
function imagem(){
 var img = document.getElementById("img")
 var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem")
 if(img.style.display == "none") { //verifica se a imagem está sendo exibida, se não estiver vai executar os comandos abaixo e se tiver vai executar o else
   img.style.display="block" //exibe a imagem
   imagem.innerHTML = "CLIQUE DE NOVO" //altera o texto
 }
 else { //se a imagem estiver sendo exibida vai executar os comandos abaixo
   img.style.display="none"; //oculta a imagem
   imagem.innerHTML = "CLIQUE AQUI" //altera o texto
 }
}
```

```css
.div1 {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.div2 {
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<ul>
  <li id="imagem" onclick="imagem()" style="cursor:pointer">CLIQUE AQUI</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/l6JAkhvfxbP61_FWN92j4ulDMXJNH3HT1DR6xrE7MtwW-2AxpZl_WLnBzTpWhCuYkbHihgBQ=w640-h400-e365" style="display:none;" id="img" height="35%" width="35%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito...Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ao clicar no texto do `<li>` ele executa a função, que vai mudar o `display` da imagem para que ela possa aparecer:

```js
function aparecer(){
   imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
   imagem.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.principal{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
.principal ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
#imagem{
   display: none;
   width: 200px;
   height: 60px;
}
#texto{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="principal">
    <ul>
       <li><a onclick="aparecer()" id="texto">Clique Aqui</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KraVclx.gif" id="imagem" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito...Muito obrigado!!!!